# Excel formula to delete a character from a string then replace another character with the same character that was deleted

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a number of coordinates and wish to remove a "." separator, then replace a "," decimal with the standard UK format "." character.

e.g. 9.811.365,054 needs to be 9811365.054

I initially used a nested substitute formula but this also removed the "." leaving only numbers i.e. 9811365054

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBE in the Immediate Window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> try

```
? replace(replace("9.811.365,054",".",""),",",".")
9811365.054
```

So pretty much you just nest two functions; first you replace all the dots with "" (*nothing*) and then replace the comma with a dot.

and an equivalent formula would be `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),",",".")` assuming `A1` is `9.811.365,054`

Comment: Great that works thanks. I'm having trouble substituting the "9.811.365,054" to a cell from another sheet e.g. 'CoordinatesSheet'!C15. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for the update vba4all. The substitute formula worked perfectly.