# How to count integers number in a cell and to do sorting in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with different numeric values. Some have format:

```
0.56
1.52
```

and some have format like:

```
6,352.00
```

To do calculations in excel i would like to substitute `"," with ""` when the number format is like 6,352.00 and to all the rest substitute `"." with ",".`

so in the result i should get:

```
0,56
1,52
6352,00
```

Then to sort them from Max to Min.

I tried to write a VBA code (that is not really correct), maybe some one can help with that?

```
Sub ChangeFormat1()
    Dim lngNumberOfCharacters As Long
    Set ws4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("atm_hh")

    ws4.Select
    Columns("C:C").Select

lngNumberOfCharacters = Len("C:C")

    If lngNumberOfCharacters > 8
    Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
       Else
           Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        End If

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("atm_hh").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("atm_hh").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("atm_hh").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:D66842")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

        End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel formula to delete a character from a string then replace another character with the same character that was deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970985/excel-formula-to-delete-a-character-from-a-string-then-replace-another-character)

Comment: i tried, to use the formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),".",",")` , but it gives me an error

Comment: use a unique character first to change from `,` to `^` for example and then run the `.` to `,` and then `^` to `.`

Comment: SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),".",",") works fine.

Comment: @Julien Marrec this formula gives me an error, i can't understand what is wrong

Comment: @Ale ... What are your regional settings? You're clearly doing this for this reason. Might be that your formula has to use ";" as delimiter, and not ",". That'd be SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";"");".";",")

Comment: @JulienMarrec You are completely right. It works with ";". Thank You! Just i'd like not to create a new column with new values, but to change format in existing one. that's why i was thinking to do it with macro.

Comment: Ok, if you're doing to do this very often, maybe VBA is the way to go then. Where in the above code you posted are you getting an error?

Comment: there is a wrong IF condition as well column with values is not defined in a right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to work with VBA

```
Sub ChangeFormat1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Set ws4 = Sheets("atm_hh")

' If you only want to replace in column A for example
With ws4.Columns("A:A")

    .Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    .Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```